# Laravel Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Tags: image, laravel, upload, null

Hello im getting the following error while upload an image using laravel: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null".

Here is my controller:

```
$imageName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = 'events';
            $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
            $upload_success = $image->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
```

Here is my view:

```
{!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

How do i save the $imageName to the pic field in my database. I tried this but it doesn't work. The field remains empty in the table.

```
$task=$request->user()->tasks()->create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'pic' => $imageName,
        ]);
```

Comment: make sure you do a multipart post. It looks like the file sis not uploaded

Answer (score 29, accepted):

in your `form:open` you need the `'files' => true` like below

```
Form::open('your_path', array('files' => true))
```

or

```
<form action="your_path" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Ok their was no enctype="multipart/form-data">  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add the following code inside your form's opening tag:
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 1):

First please check [Camilo Rojas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37125049/4721265) accepted  solution in here and then check both of input name and file parameter, names must be same.

Controller:

```
$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

View:

```
<input type="file" name="image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that no file input has been seen for that file. So, check that you input something in each file input

Answer (score 0):

if not work use this method instead
`$request->file('image')->guessExtension();`

**guessExtension** method uses the MIME type of the file to determine the extension. It checks the actual content of the file to make an educated guess about the file extension. This method can be more reliable in situations where the original file name is not indicative of the file's content.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?